# Count max substring of the same character

Tags: python, string

i want to write a function in which  it receives a string (s) and a single letter (s). the function needs to return the  length of the longest substring of this letter. i dont know why the function i wrote doesn't work
for exmaple: print(count_longest_repetition('eabbaaaacccaaddd', 'a') supposed to return '4'

```
    def count_longest_repetition(s, c):
        n= len(s)
        lst=[]
        length_charachter=0
        for i in range(n-1):
            if s[i]==c and s[i+1]==c:
                if s[i] in lst:
                    lst.append(s[i])
                    length_charachter= len(lst)
        return length_charachter
```

Comment: What id the output? What is the issue? Did you try to debug it line-by-line to understand where the issue is?

Comment: my first homeworks so i didn't even know why the if loop does not work. figured it out now, thank you.

Comment: You got multiple answers, did none of them work? You should mark the answer that is the right one to make sure other people will know (and this also give points to those who helped you).

Comment: Better to upvote the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the condition `if s[i] in lst`, nothing will be appended to 'lst' as originally 'lst' is empty and the if condition will never be satisfied. Also, to traverse through the entire string you need to use `range(n)` as it generates numbers from 0 to n-1. This should work -

```
def count_longest_repetition(s, c):
    n= len(s)
    length_charachter=0
    max_length = 0
    for i in range(n):
        if s[i] == c:
            length_charachter += 1
        else:
            length_charachter = 0
        max_length = max(max_length, length_charachter)

    return max_length
```

Comment: thank you! these are my first homeworks so every debuging the code is still hard for me and i didn't know what to do. thank you!!!

Comment: @TomShchori for such logical problems, first try to solve it on a piece of paper and then write the code for it. You'll save yourself a good deal of time and effort.

Comment: i will try it from now on. Thank you very much for the tips!

Answer (score 0):

I might suggest using a regex approach here with `re.findall`:

```
def count_longest_repetition(s, c):
    matches = re.findall(r'' + c + '+', s)
    matches = sorted(matches, key=len, reverse=True)
    return len(matches[0])

cnt = count_longest_repetition('eabbaaaacccaaddd', 'a')
print(cnt)
```

This prints: `4`

To better explain the above, given the inputs shown, the regex used is `a+`, that is, find groups of one or more `a` characters.  The sorted list result from the call to `re.findall` is:

```
['aaaa', 'aa', 'a']
```

By sorting descending by string length, we push the longest match to the front of the list.  Then, we return this length from the function.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done by `groupby`

```
from itertools import groupby
def count_longest_repetition(text,let):
    return max([len(list(group)) for key, group in groupby(list(text)) if key==let])



count_longest_repetition("eabbaaaacccaaddd",'a')

#returns 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function doesn't work because `if s[i] in lst:` will initially return false and never gets to add anything to to the `lst` list (so it will remain false throughout the loop).

You should look into regular expressions for this kind of string processing/search:

```
import re
def count_longest_repetition(s, c):
    return max((0,*map(len,re.findall(f"{re.escape(c)}+",s))))
```

If you're not allowed to use libraries, you could compute repetitions without using a list by adding matches to a counter that you reset on every mismatch:

```
def count_longest_repetition(s, c):
    maxCount = count = 0
    for b in s:
        count = (count+1)*(b==c)
        maxCount = max(count,maxCount)
    return maxCount
```