# how to find max occurrence of a letter in a string

Tags: python, string

how can I do something like this?

```
string = "ABFFFBFFFFFBF"
letter = "F"
```

maximum occurrence of F is FFFFF so output is: 5
anyone help?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61144639/count-max-substring-of-the-same-character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a more Pythonic way to do this, but this function will do the job:

```
def maxConsecutiveOccurrences(letter, string):
    count = 0
    maxCount = 0
    for ch in string:
        if ch == letter:
            count += 1
        else:
            count = 0
        if count > maxCount:
            maxCount = count
    return maxCount
```

`maxConsecutiveOccurrences("F", "ABFFFBFFFFFBF")` returns 5

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re
len(max(re.findall("F+", "ABFFFBFFFFFBF"), key=lambda x: len(x), default=[]))
```

Comment: `lambda x: len(x)` is equivalent to just `len`. You can also write the whole thing as `max(map(len, re.findall("F+", "ABFFFBFFFFFBF")))`

Answer (score -1):

```
string = "ABFFFBFFFFFBF"
letter = "F"

letter_occurence = string.count(letter)
```

By the way, you should consider not naming your variables as their type, variable names should be descriptive of what variable's usage is.

Comment: It's wrong. 5 is expected.

Comment: If you could be more descriptive in your question that'd be really helpful. Did you mean you want the largest 'group' of the target letter?

Comment: This outputs 9. The expected output is 5...